# how do I pass props to the data-...="{{ percent }}" attribute?

Tags: vue.js

how do I pass props to the data-...="{{ percent }}" attribute? how can I show the information there? Below is an example of the code:

```
<script setup>
    const props = defineProps({
        percent: {
            type: String,
            default: '0'
        }
    })
</script>


<template>
    <div class="progress-circle" data-progress="{{ percent }}">
        <div class="circle">
            <div class="full progress-circle__slice">
                <div class="progress-circle__fill"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="progress-circle__slice">
                <div class="progress-circle__fill"></div>
                <div class="progress-circle__fill progress-circle__bar"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="progress-circle__overlay">{{ percent }}</div>
    </div>
</template>
```

I'm new to vue, I tried to find the information myself, but it didn't work out.

Comment: try with a `:` before the prop.
```:data-progress="percent"```

Comment: @XavierB. does not work

Answer (score 2):

It turned out to be like this

```
:data-progress="[`${percent}`]
```